# Partitioning in Hive table

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

From a blog, in a Hive's PARTITIONING FUNCTIONS topic, they had created a table in the below schema.

```
    CREATE TABLE sales (
    sales_order_id  BIGINT,
    order_amount    FLOAT,
    order_date      STRING,
    due_date        STRING,
    customer_id     BIGINT
)
PARTITIONED BY (country STRING, year INT, month INT, day INT) ;
```

and inserting partitioned data into the sales table as below.

```
INSERT INTO sales
PARTITION (country = 'US', year = 2012, month = 12, day = 22)
SELECT  sales_order_id,
        order_amount,
        due_date,
        customer_id,
        cntry,
        yr,
        mo,
        d
FROM    source_view
WHERE   cntry = 'US'
        AND yr = 2012 
        AND mo = 12
        AND d = 22 ;
```

My doubt araise here. Since there is no field like `cntry or yr or mo or d` in the create table schema, how in the insert query they have mentioned `cntry or yr or mo or d`. How it is possible?. does the author made any mistakes in the query or is there any option available like alias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the partitioning fields are not explicitly created as columns, they are (pseudo)columns and can be queried.

From [Hive's docs](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-PartitionedTables):

> the partition you create makes a pseudocolumn on which you can query

Also (from the [Insert documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DML#LanguageManualDML-InsertingdataintoHiveTablesfromqueries)):

> Inserts can be done to a table or a partition. If the table is partitioned, then one must specify a specific partition of the table by specifying values for all of the partitioning columns.

Answer (score 0):

There is some problem with Insert.

```
INSERT INTO sales
PARTITION (country = 'US', year = 2012, month = 12, day = 22)
SELECT  sales_order_id,
    order_amount,
    due_date,
    customer_id
FROM    source_view
WHERE   cntry = 'US'
    AND yr = 2012 
    AND mo = 12
    AND d = 22 ;
```